# What does "simulatable" mean in security proofs?

Tags: zero-knowledge-proofs, provable-security, semantic-security

I am reading a security proof in a paper as follows.

*Regarding the data confidentiality of users, all related public transcripts are simply the ciphertexts $\mathcal{C}_1,\ldots,\mathcal{C}_n$. The ciphertexts are easily simulatable according to the semantic security of the public key encryption*.  How can I interpret this proof? In other words, what is meant by **simulatable**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That means you can produce a transcript by yourself (with only public knowledge), which has a sequence of values $C_1',\ldots,C_n'$ such that the distribution of $C_1',\ldots,C_n'$ and that of $C_1,\ldots,C_n$ are computationally (since public key encryption) indistinguishable.

Comment: Could you please provide me with good links or PDFs to understand how to do security proofs

Comment: @HebaMohsen https://www.crcpress.com/Introduction-to-Modern-Cryptography/Katz-Lindell/p/book/9781466570269, https://eprint.iacr.org/2016/046.pdf